# running estimates of empirical PMF and variation therein, given a RNG

Tags: algorithm, random, statistics, numerical-methods

Suppose a black-box random number generator which continually emits integer values in some interval (for the case of immediate interest, [0, 255]).  I want to estimate the probability mass function and some measure of its variation, and I want to periodically update these estimates as new samples come in, without having to store the entire set of samples so far.

- Please suggest numerically stable algorithms for computing and updating these estimates.
- Please suggest an appropriate measure of the variation in the PMF.

Answer (score 1):

The pmf of a discrete distribution is just the relative proportion of each outcome.  Create an array of length 256, initialized to all zeros.  For each value, increment the array at that index.  Scale by the total number of observations to express the result as relative proportion  (estimated probability).  Voila, instant empirical pmf, and you're only storing 256 values even if you have millions or billions of observations.  If outcomes are limited to a small subset, use a hash rather than an array.

Given the values and associated counts, you can construct whatever measures you like for central tendency or variation.  For variation you can consider range, inter-quartile range, or variance and/or standard deviation.

Comment: Sure, that's the obvious thing, but before long I'm dividing 2^40 by 2^41 and here we are in the dark jungle of floating point round-off errors.  Hence the specific request for *numerically stable* algorithms for this problem.

Comment: @Zack The counts are precise unless you're telling me you have more than 10^18 observations, in which case you already know the ratio to better than the 15 digit accuracy of double precision.  The estimated p-values are calculated as a single division of two precise quantities well within the range of exponents for a double.  Finally, you're dealing with a mere 256 numbers in the range 0-255 scaled by (at those sample sizes) incredibly precise numbers between 0 and 1.  All quantities are within a couple of orders of magnitude of each other.  Where's the numerical instability?